# Duration is not getting updated in the PKS Web-Application

Tags: 2007, administration, development, configuration, logging

We have a PKS enabled web-application in our environment, everything looks fine however the Duration (Single line in text) field is in PKS Podcasts List is not getting updated correctly while uploading a file/Item (Video/Audio).

Due to this, The Home page is showing "00:00:00" against the duration field (obviously, PKS Podcasts List is updated with "00:00:00"). I reactivated the PKS Podcast List Update Handler site feature however it does not help.

In the meantime, I found that the duration is coming up without any issues if the file does not require any Conversion (i.e., mp3,.flv) which means it could be an issue with MediaEncoder or a handler which runs after the conversion however could not find any valuable clue on this,.

Which is the Handler is responsible to update the thumbnail & Duration (is it UpdateDurationThumbnailHandler - MediaInfo ) and how it works?

Where can I find the error logs (could not find it in the ULS Log)

Even I have posted this @http://pks.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=230569.

Awaiting for your help.

Thanks!
Karthikeyan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found that it is an issue with the transcode configuration. I have made the configuration changes and it works for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

from the codeplex discussion site they have this - "If the duration is not being set verify the PKS Podcast List Update Handler site feature is activated, if activated de-activate and reactivate otherwise just activate."

http://pks.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=39662